# HTML change opacity onload using this will not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code like so:

```
<body style='opacity:0' onload='this.style.opacity=1'>
```

I would like to change opacity of body once everything is loaded. Is there a reason `this` wont work. Can I change `this` opacity? If I reference by the tag `body` it will work. For example using jquery :

```
<body style='opacity:0' onload='$("body")[0].style.opacity=1'>
```

Will work but :

```
<body style='opacity:0' onload='$(this)[0].style.opacity=1'>
```

Will not work. Can I use `this` somehow?

Comment: That looks like you are mix-mashing vanilla javascript and jQuery; change `$("body")[0].style.opacity=1` to `$("body").css('opacity', '1');`

Comment: I know. Its not the question. Why won't 'this' work. I want to use 'this'.

Comment: I know that's not the question, if I thought it was I would post an answer; I am simply helping you improve your jQuery code.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I don't mix-mash. This is just example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a reason 'this' wont work.

`this` has no context inside the `onload` that why it's not working.

> If I reference by the tag 'body' it will work

`$("body")[0]` refer to the body that why it's work, you could use `document.body` also.

> When I `onload='alert(this)'` why do I get an `object`?

Since *`this`* keyword in global scope refers to `window` object.

---

Because you're using jQuery you could avoid the inline events and use `ready` function instead of `onload` and change the style using `css()` :

```
//When the page is fully loaded
$(function(){
    //Change the opacity to 1
    $("body").css('opacity','1');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but thats not my question. I already implement this method. I am just asking why 'this' is not working but '$("body")[0]' will work. While if I do 'alert(this)' it says that 'this' is an object so its there.

Comment: Alright I understand. When I onload='alert(this)' why do I get an object? What is this object.

Comment: Since _this_ keyword in global scope refers to window object.